# count how many times a string appears within another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which points to a CSS file

```
../../css/style.css
```

I want to find out how many

```
../
```

are within the string.

How do I get this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regular expression, and get the length of the resulting array:

```
var str = "../../css/style.css";

alert(str.match(/\.\.\//g).length);
//-> 2
```

Note that `.` and `/` are special characters within regular expressions, so they need to be escaped as per my example.

Comment: Note: the `g` global regex flag is important

Comment: Note: match() can return null or an array of matches, so make sure to check for that.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need a regex for this simple case.

```
var haystack = "../../css/style.css";
var needle   = "../";
var count    = haystack.split(needle).length - 1;
```