# How to count the specific value from JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I've some code. variable rows is a object that contain data from MySQL that has attributes id, date_created, content.

```
crud.getDataTemp(2000,function(rows){
var date = new Array();
var content = new Array();
var b,j,p;
 for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
   date[i] = rows[i].date_created;
      if(date[i]){
             content[i]     = JSON.stringify(rows[i]);
        var people = content[i].match(/people/g);
        var animal = content[i].match(/animal/g);
        var plant = content[i].match(/plant/g);
        if(people != null){
            b = people.length+people.length;
        }
        if(animal != null){
            j = animal.length+animal.length;    
        }
        if(animal != null){
            p = animal.length+animal.length;
        }
    }
};
```

On my code I want to count the word which is containing 'people','animal','plant' by date. I've confused how to count all that spesific word. I've tried with my code but the result is not relevan. Anyone could help me? Thanks before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [count how many times a string appears within another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461914/count-how-many-times-a-string-appears-within-another-string)

Comment: You're counting the words correctly. Your mistake is in how you add them to the total.

Comment: You should use `[]` instead of `new Array()`. It's there for that purpose, after all. Also because `new Array(3)` is quite different from `[3]`.

Comment: so i must change iniating variable with new Array() into [] ??

Comment: Bobs, instead of adding "solved" to the title, please mark the correct answer as "accepted", by clicking the checkmark under the vote count.

Comment: @bfavaretto thanks for advice. I'm new in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
b = people.length+people.length;
```

to:

```
b = b + people.length;
```

or more simply:

```
b += people.length;
```

and similarly for the other variables.

Also, initialize your variables to 0:

```
var var b = 0, j = 0, p = 0;
```

because adding to `undefined` results in `NaN`.

Comment: I've change with your answer but the result just become NaN. what's wrong with it?

Comment: solved sir. I've change little bit my code `b += people.length` with `b++`